# Button is too small to bee seen when placed above textView?

Tags: android, button, layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@color/black">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/activity_title_main"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:text="@string/button_1"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:text="@string/button_2"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_3"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_4"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

If I try to place a button or even an image button above the textView, although I code it as:

> android_layout:alignParentTop = "true"

However in rendering layout you can see just the compressed outline of the button appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextView is aligned to parent Top (to the top of screen) with no margins. So you can't fit anything above TextView. You can:

-add top margin to TextView (don't do this)

-add button aligned to top of screen, and then add into TextView `android:layout_below="@+id/new_button"`

Comment: How do I move that image button even higher still?

Comment: This `android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"` seems to be working but it shifts everything else lower.

Comment: I don't have preview of screen and i'm not best layout guy. I don't get how are you trying to arrange new button and TextView. I thought it is something like `NewButton - (below) -> TextView - (below) -> Button - Button - Button`. So it is normal if you want fit something above `TextView` to make some space by pushing everything else down.

Comment: There is so much space it may not need to be pushed down. Anyways, thanks for your answer. It worked, mostly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this happens because you are not setting the TextView below it or you are not defining a height and it is set to `wrap_content` with a small content, if my example doesn't work, try to set a height for the ImageButton

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@color/black">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ibExample" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView
    android:text="@string/activity_title_main"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"    
    android:id="@+id/textView" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/ibExample"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:text="@string/button_1"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:text="@string/button_2"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_3"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_4"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```